# How to rotate text drawn using canvas.drawTextOnPath()?

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I am using drawTextOnPath() to create a bent text like in given picture below but I can't figure out how to rotate the text?

What I want is below highlighted in picture with arrow and circle.

[image]

What i have been able to achieve is below

[image]

So I just want to rotate these texts?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the result you want without drawTextOnPath() using:

```
        float radius = 300;
        float cx = getWidth() / 2; //Center of the circle
        float cy = getHeight() / 2; //Center of the circle

        for (int degree = 0; degree < 360; degree += 30) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(cx, cy);
            canvas.rotate(degree);
            String text = "" + degree;
            float textCenterX = radius + textPaint.measureText(text) / 2;
            float textCenterY = 0 - textPaint.getTextSize() / 2;
            if (degree < 180) {
                canvas.rotate(-90, textCenterX, textCenterY);
            } else {
                canvas.rotate(+90, textCenterX, textCenterY);
            }
            canvas.drawText("" + degree, radius, 0, textPaint);
            canvas.restore();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: without drawTextOnPath() and using this, I might will achieve something for outer text on orange boxes. But inner text which says days 2, days 3 etc. I need to flip them as well and those text are drawn on path to make them curvy. So I still need solution to flip the drawTextOnPath(). Thanks for the answer though. :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to flip the canvas and draw on it

```
canvas.save()
canvas.scale(1, -1, width / 2, height / 2)
// your drawing code
canvas.restore()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flip the text by changing the direction of the arc you are drawing on. The direction can be changed by setting a negative value to the `sweepAngle` parameter.

```java
Path path = new Path();
RectF textArcRect = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);

// positive value (90) for how you have it in your example image
// path.addArc(textArcRect, angle, 90);

// negative value (-90) to flip the text
path.addArc(textArcRect, angle, -90);

canvas.drawTextOnPath("text", path, 0, 0, paint);
```

Keep in mind that the text will now be drawn on the other side of the arc, so closer to the center. The bottom of the text follows the line of the arc. You will have to adjust the radius of the arc by the height of the text to keep the text at the same distance from the center.